# Enums with constructions in Rust

Tags: enums, rust

I have existing implementation in Java that has to be rewritten to Rust.

### Java code

```java
enum Direction {
    EAST(0), WEST(180), NORTH(90), SOUTH(270);

    private Direction(final int angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    private int angle;

    public int getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }
}
```

### Java code usage example

```java
Direction d1 = Direction.EAST;
Direction d2 = Direction.SOUTH;
```

### Rust code

So here's what I've tried:

```rust
enum Direction {
    East(u32), 
    West(u32), 
    North(u32), 
    South(u32);
}

impl Direction {
    // ???
    fn new() -> Direction // incorrect
}
```

and then I'm stuck. What do I do next?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what your Java enums look like:

```
+-----+-----+
| tid |   0 |
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
| tid |  90 |
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
| tid | 180 |
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+
| tid | 270 |
+-----+-----+
```

`tid` is the same for all four directions and identifies the type `Direction` along with its methods. Here's how, using your Rust code, `East(0)`, `Noth(90)`, `West(180)`, `South(270)` look like:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| East  |   0 |     |     |     |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| North |     |  90 |     |     |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| West  |     |     | 180 |     |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| South |     |     |     | 270 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Each constructor has a set of fields (in this case, one `int` each) which is distinct. In reality, since any given `Direction` is at most one of `East/North/East/West`, only one set of fields is used at any point in time and they use the same memory (so `Direction` actually only occupies two words).

But conceptually, the above is accurate and illustrates two problems with your Rust version. First, there is duplication: The constructor tag (N/E/S/W) is already different for all four, so the `int` fields are redundant. Second, conceptually the `int` in `North` is different from the `int` in `South`, even though it has exactly the same meaning for all of them. Furthermore, nothing stops one from creating `North(214)` or `East(180)`.

The most straightforward translation is this:

```
enum Direction { North, East, South, West }

impl Direction {
  fn get_angle(self) -> u16 {
    match self {
      Direction::East => 0,
      Direction::West => 180,
      Direction::North => 90,
      Direction::South => 270,
    }
  }
}
```

The direction is implied in the enum tag, and extracted with `get_angle`.

Answer (score 12):

delnan's answer is absolutely correct, and you should probably go with it, but there is even another way. Rust enums also can act similarly to C enums, where enum constants are essentially numerical constants. Rust allows you to write something like this:

```
enum Direction {
    East = 0,
    North = 90,
    West = 180,
    South = 270
}
```

Then you can use enum value as a number with an explicit cast:

```
let value = South as uint;
println!("{}", value);  // prints 270
```

This works because enums are essentially structs with a hidden discriminator field, which is a number. Hence values of enums which have no variants with arguments only contain this discriminator field. Its value can be accessed via a numeric cast, and you can set concrete values for different enum variants in enum definition.

What I mean is that this would only work if you need integer numbers. You can't obtain, say, strings or floating point numbers this way, like you can do in Java (where enum variants are just regular objects with arbitrary fields). If you need it, you will have to use separate getter method, like in delnan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I wasn't aware that Java enums were closed.  As such, you should probably go with delnan's answer.

I think you want something like this:

```
pub struct Direction {
    angle: int,
}

impl Direction {
    pub fn new(angle: int) -> Direction {
        Direction {
            angle: angle,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_angle(&self) -> int {
        self.angle
    }
}

pub const EAST: Direction = Direction { angle: 0 };
pub const WEST: Direction = Direction { angle: 180 };
pub const NORTH: Direction = Direction { angle: 90 };
pub const SOUTH: Direction = Direction { angle: 270 };
```

To expound: an `enum` in Rust is for listing a finite set of disjoint variants.  In other words, an `enum` would be appropriate if a `Direction` could *only* be `East`, `West`, `North` or `South` and nothing else.

Comment: The Java `Direction` also can only be E/W/N/S, not arbitrary angles.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I've never used enums in Java before.